# repackage external gradle dependencies using proguard

Tags: gradle, proguard

Is it possible to repackage external Gradle dependencies using proguard?

why?
I wanna repackage all external dependencies in our SDK because I don't wanna have a problem with dependency conflicts later when we will use this SDK in many different projects.

Comment: What do you mean by repackaging?

Comment: I wanna change original package of dependency to my own. For example for dagger: instead of using com.google.dagger, I wanna use eu.mycompany.dagger